# Octal shorthand and 7's complement

Tags: digital-logic

This question is from my digital logic class but I don't understand it. Please help me understand what it is asking me.

A1 and A2 are octal shorthand for A1 = 572053777777 and A2 = 206556400000.  The question is:

> Perform the following 1's complement fixed-point integer arithmetic operations and note whether magnitude overflow has occurred in each case: (Hint: Use 7's complement arithmetic on the other octal shorthand).
>   i) A3= A1+A2
>   ii) A3= A1-A2

The full assignment can be found [here](http://www.ece.umd.edu/class/enee350.S2012.Silio/Homework/hw2.pdf), this is problem #1.

I thought you only take complements when you want to do subtraction. Can't I just do the subtraction in octal form? Can someone help me understand what the questions are asking?

Comment: 1's complement is a different binary encoding scheme than the now more popular 2's complement.  In 2's complement you can pretty much add and subtract without having to consider whether any of the numbers are negative or not.  In 1's complement, negative numbers need to be detected and handled differently from positive numbers.  1's complement also has the special case of "negative zero".

Answer (score 1):

The use of the phrase '1's complement fixed-point integer arithmetic operations' simply means there can be negative numbers, and how they are representative.
See paragraph for ones' complement system on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%27s_complement

In that situation 1's complement is an adjective, describing the numbering system.

That is not to be confused with the command (verb) to take (find, calculate, etc.) the complement.